# Выдвигающаяся панель сбоку

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**Цель:** Осуществить в приложении возможность выдвигать панель сбоку.

**Условия:**

- Панель должна выдвигаться движением пальца (*Swipe'ом*);
- У выдвигающейся панели должна торчать небольшая часть (*Типа

  петелька, за которую тянуть :)* );
- Панель должна выдвигаться справа.

> Вот очень хороший пример того, что требуется: [Ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/). Он идеально
>   подходит по всем параметрам, но экран выдвигается только снизу, а нужно
>   сбоку.

**Вопрос:** Как можно осуществить задуманное?

*Пишу на Kotlin, но если вы знаете как это осуществить на Java, то тоже подойдёт.*

Answer (score 0):

В Android Studio есть шаблон активити Navigation Drawer Activity, где сделано именно то, о чем вы говорите. Создайте, посмотрите что получится, погуглите непонятные части. Если останутся вопросы - спрашивайте

Comment: Смотрел этот вариант. Насколько я знаю,там нельзя сделать "Петельку" (У выдвигающейся панели должна торчать небольшая часть).
Или можно?

Comment: Мне кажется вполне возможным. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Как я понимаю, не получилось, да? Вы напишите результат хотя бы. А то люди думают, что тут уже ответ дан и не предлагают своих вариантов.

Comment: не добрался еще) Я точно могу сказать как привязать к движению шторки другой объект, но вот не уверен как реализовать обратную ситуацию, когда вы тяните петельку заставить двигаться шторку. Если вам хватит открытия по клику - хоть сейчас набросаю пример